# How to change the default clock (city) in gnome-clocks?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-clocks

I just installed gnome-clocks and by default it took on a different city than my city. I can add my city but can't delete the default city or make my city the default.

There is no guidance either in the documentation or on the internet.

Does anyone have any hints?

Thanks.

Update: I found that the default city is removed by changing org/gnome/clocks/geolocation to OFF using dconf-editor. But still can't make added city as the default.

Comment: No. I do not use any snap software. However, I did some more research and found that I can tweak in dconf-editor for partial solution of removing the default clock. We have to set org/gnome/clocks/geolocation to OFF. It will remove the default clock, but can't make any added clock as the default.

Comment: No. It is in sync with system clock. My issue is more or less resolved as I can remove the unwanted default clock of the same time-zone, which could not be selected in the gnome-clocks GUI for deletion. Due to geolocation data from the ISP it was taking Hyderabad, India as default, whereas my city is Visakhapatnam, India. Time-zone is same, but sunrise and sunset times are different.

Comment: Please post what you did to solve your problem as an answer below to help future readers.

Comment: @pomsky, I will when I resolve my issue fully - it's resolved partially at present, which I noted as update in the question.